# How to set nested block template to an attribute

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm having trouble setting the template of my 'InnerBlocks' to be a variable/attribute. I can set a template and use it without issue, but I eventually want to have a dropdown with 3 different templates so I would like to be able to have the template set to a particular attribute.

Taking a look at my edit function I have tried `template={dashboardStyle}` and `template={ {dashboardStyle} }` but neither seem to work.

```
import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText, InspectorControls, InnerBlocks } = wp.editor;

const dashboard2x2 = [
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
];

const dashboard3x3 = [
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
    ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item'],
];


registerBlockType('wpress-blocks/dashboard', {
    title: __('dashboard'), // Block title
    icon: 'dashboard', // Block icon from Dashicons → https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/
    category: 'common', // Block category — Group blocks together based on common traits E.g. common, formatting, layout widgets, embed
    keywords: [
        __('block'),
        __('dashboard')
    ],
    attributes:{
        dashboardStyle: {
            type: 'string',
            default: 'dashboard3x3',
        },
    },

    edit: function (props) {
        const { attributes, className } = props
        const dashboardStyle = attributes.dashboardStyle

        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <InnerBlocks 
                    template={dashboard3x3}
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: function (props) {
        return (
            <div>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

The code functions correctly as is, but when I have tried to use the attribute `dasbhoardStyle` in place of naming the template explicitly (in the ways listed), I get a console error that `n is undefined`.

I figure my syntax is off, but I have not been able to find an example that does this same sort of thing, and I haven't found anything in the documentation on how to do this, so I'm really just guessing in what I've tried so far. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else finds this and is wondering the same thing, this is what I came up with as a solution:

first I defined the template styles in an array called 'templates'

```
const templates = {
    dashboard2x2: [
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item2x2', { className: 'col-md-6'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item2x2', { className: 'col-md-6'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item2x2', { className: 'col-md-6'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item2x2', { className: 'col-md-6'} ],
    ],
    dashboard3x2: [
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
        ['wpress-blocks/dashboard-item3x2', { className: 'col-md-4'} ],
    ]
}
```

Then added this to my edit function:

```
const activeTemplate = templates[attributes.dashboardStyle];
```

Added a dropdown to allow me to select between the styles:

```
<InspectorControls>             
     <SelectControl                     
          label={ __( 'Select Dashboard Style' ) }
          value={ attributes.dashboardStyle } 
          onChange={ ( dashboardStyle ) => { setAttributes( { dashboardStyle } ) } }                        
          options={ [
               { value: 'dashboard2x2', label: '2 by 2' },
               { value: 'dashboard3x2', label: '3 by 2' },                                          
          ] }                       
     />
</InspectorControls>
```

and then changed my InnerBlocks to use the template 'activeTemplate' like so:

```
<InnerBlocks 
     template = { activeTemplate }
/>
```